# Are there any highly functional web browsers that run scripting languages other than JavaScript?

Tags: browser, lisp

I want to learn LISP, but I also want to build web software.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) which translates a Lisp dialect to Javascript.

Comment: This is the way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Grail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grail_%28web_browser%29) can (could) run client-side Python.  Of course, nobody uses it, so it won't really help you today.

I think, instead of asking for browsers that run something other than Javascript, you should be looking for web *servers* you can extend with Lisp.  There's a number of those around.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely reasonable.  I'm more concerned about what we're missing out on functionality-wise versus adoption though.  With things like Chrome OS effectively being a 'browser in a box', limiting our toolsets seems inefficient. Thanks for the Grail tip.